# Unknown provider in .config() with custom Provider

Tags: angularjs, service-provider, angularjs-injector

I've got this in app.js:

```
angular.module('App',[]).config(['TranslationProvider', function (TranslationProvider) {
//codes...
}]);
```

And this service in another file:

```
angular.module('App')

.provider('Translation', function() {
var translations = {foo:"bar"}

this.$get = function(){
    return translations;
};

});
```

No 404 error with the service js file, but when angular injector try to instantiate it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TranslationProvider
```

I've followed the angjs documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: can you try: config(function ($TranslationProvider) {

Comment: Probably move the provider definition to another module and require that module from `App`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Angular 1.2.x. The order of the calls matter. When you call `provide` before `config` it works. It also works with Angular 1.3.x regardless of the order.

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there.

First the config:

```js
angular.module('App')
    .config(["TranslationProvider", function(theProvider) {
        console.log("in config" + theProvider)
        theProvider.setName("some name");
    }]);
```

The error you were having was due to you using the constructor function as an argument.

Now your provider:

```js
angular.module('App')
    .provider('Translation', function TranslationProvider() {
        var translations = {foo:"bar", name:""};
        var dynamicName;

        this.setName = function(configName) {
            dynamicName = configName;
        };

        this.$get = function(){
            translations.name = dynamicName;
            return translations;
        };
    });
```

Also note that an anonymous function (i.e.  `.provider('Translation', function () {`) could also have been used and the code would have worked just as well.

Using it all in a controller:

```js
angular.module('App')
   .controller('MyController', [
    '$scope',
    'Translation',

    function ($scope,
              translationProvider) {

        $scope.modal = {};
        $scope.projects = [];

        console.log(translationProvider)
        $scope.foo = translationProvider;
    }]);
```

Comment: _using the constructor function as an argument_ ??? Angular passes the arguments, not the OP.

Comment: @zeroflagL yes. But writing function(TranslationProvider) vs function(theProvider) means two very different things. The first treats the TranslationProvider as constructor function which caused the error. The second (i.e. function(theProvider) ) is the value that gets injected and is what works. Makes sense?

Comment: Not at all. They are the same, just with different parameter names. If the OP didn't use the array annotation, then it would make a difference, because Angular would look for a provider named `theProvider`.

Comment: Sorry. That's not my experience. Run the code that I have included. Once with theProvider and then again with TranslationProvider. The code I think speaks for itself :)

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Hmmm. That's interesting as it did on my system.

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6b8GbnYznnjY1BKIQlpv?p=preview). maybe you used Angular 1.3.x or had a different order.

Comment: That's fair. I am using 1.3.10